# How to "separation of concern"?

Tags: database, oop, aspect

**Seperation of concern**:

A method named  '**prepare_product_data**' returns :

```
 product_data = { id : 1, name : 'iphone 7' , url : 'iphone-7' }
```

A method named **save( db_table , data )** takes only two arguments - daabase table name and the prepared data. It's sole purpose is to save the data to the specified table.

But now in the product url is duplicate and cannot be overriden rather needs to be stored by modifying the url, say by adding a random number in the end. So when colliding for duplicate it should catch the database duplicate error and then modify the url. So on first duplicate the

```
 product_data = { id : 1, name : 'iphone 7' , url : 'iphone-7-X' }
```

The **save** method only concerns about saving  not checking for duplicates, and even if it checks it should not handle anything specific about 'product' table. That won't be separation of concern. In this case how do we do separation of concern?

Comment: Have a third method which specifically saves *product data* and contains the logic to deal with duplicates…!?

Comment: @deceze Isn't that writing the same code (I mean most of it) twice?

Comment: You don't have to go overboard with DRYness, it's unrealistic and impractical. You don't consolidate all calls to `strlen` (or whatever) into one place, and there's no reason to have only exactly one place where you make calls to your database.

Comment: Also note that *separation of concerns* means that one particular part should only be responsible for one particular thing, not that there must be one and only one part which does some similar thing. I.e. you shouldn't have one database function which handles all possible cases and has a thousand parameters; on the contrary, you should have one database function for each specific case.